# Creating my first SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure, which prints out a message listing all customers and their contactNum who have NOT paid. I want it to look like a report for admin staff. I'm not sure how to go about this so any help would be great!

I have created a query for this but I'm stuck on how to create the stored procedure.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    booking.bookingID,
    booking.totalCost,
    booking.bookingDate,
    booking.paymentConfirmation,
    customers.customersID,
    customers.firstname,
    customers.surname,
    customers.contactNum
FROM 
    booking 
INNER JOIN 
    customers ON booking.customerID = customers.customersID
WHERE
    paymentConfirmation = 'False'
ORDER BY 
    bookingDate ASC
```

My knowledge on stored procedures is very minimal, thanks for your patience.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MySP AS`

Comment: You should try google before asking, I am sure you would find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:  [SEE HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms345415.aspx)

```
USE zachtravelagency
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.mySP1
AS 

    SELECT 
    booking.bookingID,
    booking.totalCost,
    booking.bookingDate,
    booking.paymentConfirmation,
    customers.customersID,
    customers.firstname,
    customers.surname,
    customers.contactNum


    FROM booking INNER JOIN customers
    ON booking.customerID= customers.customersID

    Where
    paymentConfirmation = 'False'

    ORDER BY bookingDate ASC
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is whole code of your requirement

```
USE zachtravelagency
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetAdminReport] 
AS 
 BEGIN
 SELECT 
booking.bookingID,
booking.totalCost,
booking.bookingDate,
booking.paymentConfirmation,
customers.customersID,
customers.firstname,
customers.surname,
customers.contactNum


FROM booking INNER JOIN customers
ON booking.customerID= customers.customersID

Where
paymentConfirmation = 'False'

ORDER BY bookingDate ASC


END
GO
```